# Firebase realtime database cannot query with integer

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have sample of data like below

```
{
  "random_key 1" : {
    "id": 0,
    "text": "This is text"
  },
  "random_key 2" : {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "This is text"
  }
}
```

I want to Query to get the node with 'id' equal to 1.

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
database.orderByChild("id").equalTo(1)
```

But this code return error because follow google document by this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

The library is only support for Double, Boolean and String. I am really confuse now. How it possible?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Thanks for your answer .The error message like this:
`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
@NonNull public open fun equalTo(p0: Boolean): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
@NonNull public open fun equalTo(p0: Double): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query
@NonNull public open fun equalTo(@Nullable p0: String?): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, You are right.

**The library is only support for Double, Boolean and String**.

Also your `query` is right. As firebase consider `1` as `double`. So, your `query` should work. Check below:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String textValue = childSnapshot.child("text").getValue(String.class);
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**Update for Kotlin:** In Jave, `int` to `double` is automatically convert using assignment operator as lower type can be converted to higher type implicitly. This is also known as **implicit type casting or type promotion**.

But in Kotlin, there is nothing about implicit type casting. You have to do it yourself using [toDouble()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-double.html). Check below:

```
val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val query = databaseReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(1.toDouble())
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(dataSnapshot: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.children.forEach { childSnapshot-> 
             
            val textValue = childSnapshot.child("text").getValue(String::class.java)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I received this error:
`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: @NonNull public open fun equalTo(p0: Boolean): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query @NonNull public open fun equalTo(p0: Double): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query @NonNull public open fun equalTo(@Nullable p0: String?): Query defined in com.google.firebase.database.Query`
Totally cannot compile the code. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @danh-nguyen, Sorry for the kotlin syntax. I have updated my answer. Please check.